How to dynamically add, modify and remove Class Mappings and Entities in existing SessionFactory without rebuilding it?
I’m facing significant challenges with NHibernate in my .NET application, particularly around dynamically creating tables and altering schemas at runtime. My application needs to create millions of tables concurrently and occasionally modify their schemas. Currently, each table creation or schema alteration involves creating new Configuration and SessionFactory instances, leading to severe memory overhead and performance bottlenecks.
What I've Tried:

Dynamic Mappings: Using NHibernate 5.4's support for dynamic persistent models (Chapter 4. Persistent Classes (nhibernate.info)), we generate XML mapper strings using the System.xml.Linq and add them to the configuration.

Single Configuration Instance: I developed a custom class inheriting from NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration to dynamically add and remove mappings.

SessionFactory Overhead: Despite maintaining a single Configuration instance, I couldn't avoid creating new SessionFactory instances, which consume excessive memory (e.g., over 300MB for 2,000 tables).


My Needs:
I need a solution to maintain a single SessionFactory instance that supports:

Dynamic Table Creation: Adding new tables at runtime.
Schema Alteration: Modifying existing table schemas.
Low Memory Usage: Avoiding the high memory overhead from multiple SessionFactory instances.

Key Constraints:

NHibernate Dependency: Switching ORM solutions is not feasible.
Security: I rely on NHibernate’s thread safety and security features.
Performance: The Solutions must minimize execution time and memory usage.

I understand that SessionFactory is immutable, but in my scenario, adding newly persistent entities to the existing SessionFactory is preferable to building a new one. Despite my efforts, rebuilding the SessionFactory is costly (e.g., over 6 GB for 50,000 mappers and 12.27 GB for 100,000 mappers).
I am also open to solutions that allow me to perform CRUD operations and utilize ICriteria, ISession, and ITransaction features without a SessionFactory. My implementation heavily relies on ICriteria, so being able to perform these operations without a SessionFactory is also acceptable.
I kindly seek advice on maintaining a single SessionFactory instance to support dynamic schema changes and table creation, ensuring low memory usage and execution time.

NHibernate Dependency: Switching ORM solutions is not feasible. I was about to suggest Dapper or similar. Why other ORM is not possible? Is this a legacy project using NH? If so, how was it handling this situation so far? If this is new requirement, can you keep your existing code and use Dapper or similar for new feature?

Thanks for your comment and idea.
Yeah, Our application was implemented 7 years ago using .NET and NHibernate. The required features have already been implemented, so modifying it to use a different ORM-based architecture would be an additional overhead. We’re not just creating tables dynamically; we also perform complex query retrievals on these tables and apply most filters to them. Our application is heavily dependent on NHibernate’s ICriteria interface, so switching to another ORM is not a feasible solution for us.

I'm not entirely sure about this solution, but it might be helpful for your investigation. The SessionFactory in NHibernate is generally designed to be immutable for certain purposes, such as security and performance. However, if your goal is to add a new model to the SessionFactory without rebuilding it, there is a way to achieve this by making some modifications to the NHibernate source code.
One approach could involve adding a method to the Configuration class to integrate the new model into the existing SessionFactory. Additionally, you might need to adjust the SessionFactoryImpl class to allow for the necessary mutability, particularly by modifying certain readonly dictionary properties. This would enable the addition of the new model, handle caching, and set up pre-HQL and ICriteria queries, all without requiring a full rebuild of the SessionFactory.
Modify Configuration Class
public ISessionFactory AddMapperInSessionFactory(SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory, string MapperName)
{
        // Implement the logic to find the newly added model in the configuration and pass it
        return sessionFactory.AddMapperInSessionFactory(this, mapping, settings, GetInitializedEventListeners(), newmodel);
}

Modify SessionFactoryImpl Class
Convert the readonly dictionaries into mutable dictionaries:
// Original readonly dictionary
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheBase> _allCacheRegions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheBase>();

// Modified mutable dictionary
private IDictionary<string, CacheBase> _allCacheRegions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheBase>();

Implement the logic to add the new model:
public ISessionFactory AddMapperInSessionFactory(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners, PersistentClass model, Mapping.Collection collectionmodel = null)
{
        // Implement logic to integrate the new model, manage caches, and handle ICriteria
        entityPersisters[model.EntityName] = persister;

        if (collectionmodel != null)
        {
            collectionPersisters[collectionmodel.Role] = collectionpersister;
        }

        // Additional initialization and validation steps
        return this;
}

Implement these methods in a fully secure manner to ensure the security of the SessionFactory and to meet your performance requirements.

thanks for your answer. though modifying in the nhibernate soure code is very cumbersome process, since we need to very carefyl in every nhibernate release update.
